# HBase - Any critical impact (performance, sizing, etc.) when considering number of columns in table

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Should I be avoiding adding additional columns to my HBase tables when I don't really need this data for now? I mean, today I'm getting a lot of details coming into my process, some of the attributes I need to save to HBase and some are not required. Should I just save all the input I'm getting, just in case I will need it in the future? What will be the impact here? Just to help to understand the query better, how will saving 400 attributes (in 400 columns), instead of 200, impact my system?
Regarding available size, for sure, I will need double the size (this has cost impact, be it on AWS or on-premise). What about reading from the table (query it using some API or extracting the data to some file)? What about writing to the table? Anything else?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The impact to your system might be considerable, depending on:

1. What your query patterns are
2. How you've designed your rowkeys
3. How you've divided your columns into column families

...among other factors.  Having 400 columns is well within the abilities of HBase to handle, but you must make informed decisions up front about how your table is designed.

For example, if you propose to have only a single column family and put all your columns in it, then you will definitely see a performance impact when querying if you go from 200 to 400.

On the other hand, if you create two column families ('A' and 'B') and put your most-often queried columns in A, and your least-often queried columns in B, then you're much more likely to see your queries perform efficiently.

If you haven't already, I would suggest reading this section in the HBase Reference Guide:

https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#schema

to get a sense of how performance and efficiency might be affected by choices you make when designing your table.

Comment: Thanks DMH! If I understood correctly, if the table is built right, the performance will not be impacted. What if currently some columns are not needed, but later on I decide to start using these, can I move the columns from family A to family B? 
What about the disk space? For sure there will be an impact which will lead to frequent requests to upscale (aws) and to higher costs...

Comment: Not knowing all the details of your application and/or data I am hesitant to make a strong prescription either way... but yes, if you want to keep the "extra" columns in HBase then keeping them in their own column family is a sound idea to avoid impacting your query performance.  And yes, they will still use disk space.